# Statements generalizing representability of integers by binary quadratic forms to $n$-variable higher homogeneous forms?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

Representing integers through the theory of binary quadratic forms is a well studied topic. We know that given $a,b,c\in\Bbb N$, based on discrimant $b^2-4ac$, we can study the representability of integers $n\in\Bbb N$ by $$ax^2+bxy+cy^2$$

One simple theorem states that if discriminant is coprime to $n$ with $\Big(\frac{b^2-4ac}n\Big)=1$, there is at least one primitive form with same discriminant that represents $n$.

What is the state of art generalizing similar facts known in binary quadratic forms to general $m$-variate higher homogeneous forms?

What is a good reference for these facts?

Comment: The obvious generalization is to $n$-ary quadratic forms. They still satisfy the Hasse principle, as shown by Hasse-Minkowski. In general, the circle method can deal with degree $d$ forms as long as $n$ is large with respect to $d$ (see for example the seminal work of Birch). Another generalization is to norm-form equations; here the observation is that binary quadratic forms are norm forms for quadratic field extensions of the rationals.

Comment: Pretty cool however I am not familiar with results you are talking about? Could you pleaase post a full address of details?

Comment: You can think of a lot of ideas. Better more clearly define the issue.  For example what kind of numbers required.  Although this form can always lead to the Pell equation.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao Could you elaborate your idea?

Comment: @individ I think representing prime numbers would be a good start if one can also give associated composition laws.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao Isn't that only for rational numbers, not integral?

Comment: @WillSawin Would you by any chance know any similar statements and references?